# Standard notation for the the collection of all *minimal* elements of the set of all upper bounds?

Tags: notation, order-theory

Let $(P,\leq)$ denote a poset and suppose $X \subseteq P$. Then the minimum element of the set of all upper bounds of $X$ can be denoted $\operatorname{sup} X$, or $\bigvee X$. Is there a similar notation for the collection of all *minimal* elements of the set of all upper bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none, as far as I know.

However, the set of all upper bound of a subset $X$ is sometimes denoted by
$X^\uparrow$ and the set of all minimal elements of a subset $Y$
is sometimes denoted by $\min(Y)$; this gives us the notation $\min(X^\uparrow)$.

I think this is a usable notation, because if one wants to prove something about the set in question, the proof will probably use the set $X^\uparrow$. So it probably did not make sense to invent an "irreducible" notation.